# Custom TableView iOS

Tags: ios, storyboard, customization, tableview

I have made an tableview in Storyboard with custom cells:

[image: Table]

How can i Fill and make this table as on the picture in the code with storyboard?
Thanks in regard.

Comment: http://blog.spritebandits.com/2012/03/13/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xibs-step-by-step-tutorial/

Comment: You need to subclass UITableViewCell

Comment: @Bhargavi Does it also work with Storyboard?

Comment: before asking questions like this please try doing it and ask for help if you get stuck some where.

Answer (score 0):

In the ViewController in Storyboard that contains the UITableView, Drag a UITableViewCell inside the UITableView ans customize it.
Make new Class inherits from UITableViewCell to handle all functionality regards to this Cell.
Also in StoryBoard change the Class of the custom cell with the new class you made